# How can I list methods directly defined in a class (not inherited)?

Tags: python

I am looking for something along the lines of `dir()`, but want to filter out non-instancemethods and attributes that are defined in super class/es.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for python 2.x:

```
[name for name, method in Class.__dict__.iteritems() if callable(method)]
```

for python 3.x:

```
[name for name, method in Class.__dict__.items() if hasattr(method,'__call__')]
```

Comment: It seems to me that `inspect` should have something to do this a little nicer ... (but I don't know for sure -- I haven't looked)